# Unable to add plugins to cordova project. npm error?

Tags: node.js, cordova, gradle, plugins, npm

I have a Cordova application and want to add a plugin to my Cordova project. It worked yesterday!

What I did:

- Updated Android Studio to 3.x
- Updated Cordova

If I want use the cordova add  command, I get this error:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you check if there was a typo in your custom plugin setting the version somewhere to "0.1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard Reset it: Try to remove that plugin you installed yesterday, maybe do a clean install of Cordova or update all dependencies and add missing through Gradle and then finally go for installing the plugins. Somehow, I feel that Cordova version or some dependency mismatch is giving birth to such problems.